# Bootstrap 3 glyphicons on Windows Phone

Tags: css, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

To display Bootstrap 3.0 glyphicons on Windows Phone, I was forced to add the following section to my `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

The problem now, is that it breaks development in Debug mode on DEV machines. The error is:

500.19 Internal Server Error
*Cannot add duplicated collection entry of type 'mimeMap' with unique key attribute 'fileExtension' set to '.woff'.*

How can I solve it? I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Win 8.1.

Thanks.

Comment: You can check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28051721/3901618

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the following transform on the `Web.Release.config` file. In this way it only affects production website:

```
<system.webServer xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```